# More elegant array multiplication than multiple concat statements

Tags: javascript, array

**Background**

Trevor wishes to duplicate an array, transforming it by multiplying its elements four times.

**Existing Solution**

```
//
var atest =   ['a','b','c'];
var btest =   [];
btest     =   atest.concat(atest).concat(atest).concat(atest);
//
console.log(btest.length);  // btest.length == 12
console.log(btest);         // ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

**Goal**

Trevor does not like this because it is ugly. Can you help Trevor find his happy place again? It's bugging Trevor.

Comment: Trevor should come here and post the question himself so he can provide some context as to why he wants to multiply the array's elements 4 times.

Comment: Will it always be 4, might a loop not make sense?

Comment: **//why he wants to multiply the array's elements 4 times//** Why not?

Comment: **//Will it always be 4, might a loop not make sense?//** A loop is fine, but something more like the way this can be done in ruby is preferred:

`print (['a','b','c'] * 4).inspect`

that gives the desired outcome

Comment: I am afraid that Trevor would need to write a helper function for that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one that uses `call` and manually concat `a`

```
var a = ['a','b','c'], b = Array.prototype.concat.call(a,a,a,a);
```

If you wanted an easy way to variably add `a`, just change `i`:

```
for(var a=["a","b","c"],b=[],i=4;i--;) b.push.apply(b,a);
```